# How can we pass a 2D array/vector as a function parameter in C++?

Tags: c++, 2d-vector

Tried using globally declaration, but that is not useful for me.

Comment: You should avoid global declarations for many reasons. If you want to use some properties from one function in another function, pass the property as a argument to that function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a 2D array to a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function)

Answer (score 1):

```
int connection(vector< vector<int>> &gridOfNodes,int m,int n)
{
//Your code goes here

//Accessing Vector sample
if(gridOfNodes[i][j] == 1)
{

}
}



int main() 
{ 


 int n,m;
 cin>>n>>m;
 // initialize Vector
 vector<vector<int> > vec( n , vector<int> (m, 0));

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cin>>vec[i][j]; 

 //Function calling 
 cout << connection(vec,m,n);

 return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Also worth adding some indentation and `const` to the argument to avoid accidental mutations.

Answer (score 1):

**2D Array:**

If you don't want it (the second dimension or both of them as `const`) to be defined in global scope, then I assume your function is in the local scope of `main()` or some other function - If yes then just define the dimensions and use:

```cpp
function(int array[dim1][dim2])
```

or

```cpp
function(int array[][dim2], int dim1)
```

**2D Vector:**

```cpp
function(std::vector<std::vector<int>>const &vec)
```

**Vector Array:**

```cpp
function(std::array<std::vector<int>>const &vecarray)
```

Note that the use of `const` specifier is only required when you are passing the 2D vector by reference. If your passing it by value, copies will be made and your original 2D vector won't be modified. (For cases such as when you would return something from the function and not be bothered about its values changed inside the function body)